# What is the fastest way to get any object JSON from the database to the client without leaving behind opportunities for SQL injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, json, model-view-controller, json.net

What is the fastest way to get JSON from the database to the client without leaving behind opportunities for SQL injection?

I am looking at paging, insert, update, delete, sort, etc... against any table in my schema.

Comment: use prepared queries for complete protection from sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on what data you are querying. 
The fact you are using JSON doesnt have anything to do with sql injection - its more of the calls to the database that would be a concern. 
On the server side do not form any dynamic sql. 
1. Use stored procedures (and do not include any dynamic sql in a stored proc - if you do make sure you use sp_executesql and not exec, as sp_executesql can take a parameterized query 2. use parameterized queries
3. use an ORM (ex. entity framework) which uses parameterized queries behind the scenes anyways.

try not to use any dynamic sql - if you must for some reason then make sure you use parameterized queries.

then on your result from your controller simply return

return Json(yourModel);